# Warning at top of website & top menu gone

Tags: functions, menus, hooks, parameter

This warning  has appeared at the top of our website, and our top menu bar has disappeared:

Warning: call_user_func_array) expects parameter! +~ be
a valid callback, function
'smartwp_remove_wp_block_library_css' not found or
invalid function name in
/home/customer/www/stpetersmedford.org/public_r
includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 307

I don’t know how to decipher this message nor how to fix the problem. Are the two things related (disappearance of top menu, this warning)?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It looks like at some point you followed this: https://smartwp.com/remove-gutenberg-css/ But didn't properly delete all the code. Or you renamed the function without renaming the action callback.

Answer (score 0):

This function, `call_user_func_array()` is called by `add_filter()` (or `add_action()`) that was not declared properly. Scan the code for something like:

`add_filter('something', 'smartwp_remove_wp_block_library_css')`

to find the culprit. If you do find it and it wasn't something you added/changed, you will have to troubleshoot to determine why this function was not declared/found.

The top menu is still there - you can see it very faintly at the very top of the page as you mouse over the area just above the warning message.

One last thing - it looks like you have `display_errors` enabled, which is not good practice for a public facing website.

Comment: How do I disable display_errors?

Comment: `display_errors` could be enabled in wp-config.php, or in .htaccess, or in php.ini (you need to determine which one is loaded in your configuration), or even in httpd.conf. Start with wp-config.php to see if that's where it is enabled - reference [https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/).